# MySQL взаимодействие таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql

Как я могу организовать такое действие: если поле `A` пользователя `246` в поле `idPage` в таблице tab1  `= NULL`, а в таблице tab2 есть есть этот id, то поле `A` = 'True'

Я ещё слаб в MySql, пожалуйста приведите строку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE
  tab1
  JOIN tab2 ON (tab1.idPage = tab2.id)
SET
  tab1.A = TRUE
WHERE
  tab1.idPage = 246 AND
  tab1.A IS NULL
```